# How to get focus for EditText and navigate using D-pad in Android TV

Tags: android, search, android-edittext, android-tv, d-pad

I am creating suggestion based search feature using `EditText` & `PopupWindow`due to some GUI requirements. Search and suggestions are working perfect, but I'm unable to navigate through search `EditText` and list items of `PopupWindow` via Dpad.

following is the layout of my whole screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/center_baseline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_baseline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/center_baseline"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom_baseline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_baseline"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom_baseline"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_shelf_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="@dimen/top_shelf_image_alpha"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_top_bar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alpha="@dimen/home_screen_top_bar_alpha"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_logo_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_app_logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team_search_bar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_screen_search_bar_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_screen_logo_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/lb_search_bar_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_content_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/home_title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/home_screen_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/team_title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="600dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_screen_content_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:maxWidth="600dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="@string/short_description"
        android:textColor="@color/team_desciption_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/home_screen_short_description" />

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name=".ui.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/top_baseline"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/team_search_bar"
    tools:context=".ui.HomeActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`BrowseFragment` contains some details in card. Everything is working fine except I am not able to navigate through `EditText` and `ListView` items of `PopupWindow`.

Is there any way from which I can make navigation work using D-pad???

Comment: You mean from `Edit Text` to list items below it want getting focused via `D-pad` ?

Comment: Yes,its  not getting focused there. Also it not getting focus from BrowseFragment to Edittext.

Comment: I tried this but its also not working: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html#d-pad-navigation

Comment: Yes most probably TV navigation should work in this case which i used.

Comment: Its not working in case of my layout. Once my browsefragment gets focus, I'm unable to navigate to anyother view in my layout.

Comment: Show me  your scenario exactly by posting mock up or screen shot that will be easy to understand.

Comment: Could you show me with more description with your `layout` and `screen shot` of what problem occurs ?

Comment: @jaydroider I have posted complete layout file in my question.